# MongoDB: Couldn't add user - not authorized (CloudFoundry)

Tags: mongodb, cloud-foundry, swisscomdev

I have a MongoDB (Service Plan: small) and I would like to create an additional user but it seems I dont have the necessary privileges to do so.

```
db.createUser({ user: "whateverusername" , pwd: "whateverpassword", roles: ["userAdminAnyDatabase", "dbAdminAnyDatabase", "readWriteAnyDatabase"]})
```

> Failed to execute script.
>
> Error: couldn't add user: not authorized on XXXXXXX to execute
>   command { createUser: "whateverusername", pwd: "xxx", roles: [
>   "userAdminAnyDatabase", "dbAdminAnyDatabase", "readWriteAnyDatabase"
>   ], digestPassword: false, writeConcern: { w: "majority", wtimeout:
>   600000.0 } } :
>   _getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13 DB.prototype.createUser@src/mongo/shell/db.js:1290:15 @(shell):1:1

and I cant list the users:

```
db.system.users.find();
```

> Error: error: {   "ok" : 0,   "errmsg" : "not authorized on XXXXXXX to
>   execute command { find: \"system.users\", filter: {} }",  "code" : 13,
>     "codeName" : "Unauthorized" }

Is this restriction intended? Is there a way to get the readWriteAnyDatabase role? Am I doing something wrong?

I really appreciate any help you can provide!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add users through CloudFoundry. Either bind the service to an app, which will create a user to be used by that app, or create a service key which is meant for all other purposes (mostly for the cases where a human needs to interact with the database).

Here's the docs on how to bind a service to an app: https://docs.developer.swisscom.com/devguide/services/application-binding.html

A tutorial for it: https://docs.developer.swisscom.com/tutorial-go/bind-service.html

And here's how to create service keys: https://docs.developer.swisscom.com/devguide/services/service-keys.html

Comment: Binding a service works as expected but the user that I get with MongoDB service bind is a user without role readWriteAnyDatabase and I need somehow a user who has this role.

Comment: @AndrásTornai MongoDB and MongoDB Enterprise service instances on Swisscom Application Cloud only grant access to a single database, thus the role readWriteAnyDatabase is not available.